# How to bind an object to a list?

Tags: c#, object, generics, reference, bind

This is not a windows form app, I'm not sure I'm using the correct terminology. I'm trying to bind an object to a list so when the object is modified outside of the list, those changes are reflected in the list. I'm not entirely sure how to start, my searches just keep returning "winform" answers to a datasource but this is not what I want. Here is what I have so far:

You can copy this code into a console app if you wish to test it. Notice the foreach that loops through go.Getcomponents() does not show the names because I don't think the object modified is still referenced when pulled out of the list. Essentially I'm trying to modify the object outside the list but when that object is modified the object in the list is also modified.

It is important that it can be serialized because the GameObject will be transferred across a network and data within it will be read by a server.

```
class Test
{
    public void TestStart()
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject(); //create GameObject
        Dog dog = go.AddComponent<Dog>(); //Add a Dog component to the GameObject
        dog.name = "Fluffy";  //name the dog fluffy, this should be reflected in the GenericComponent list of GameObject
        Dog dog2 = go.AddComponent<Dog>();
        dog2.name = "Fuzzy";

        //loop through all dog components in GameObject go, doesn't print dog names :(
        foreach (Dog dg in go.GetComponents<Dog>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dg.name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class GameObject
{
    List<GenericComponent<Object>> componentList = new List<GenericComponent<Object>>();

    //returns first found in list.
    public T GetComponent<T>()
    {
        return (T)componentList.Find(c => c.component.GetType() == typeof(T)).component;
    }
    //add a component to component list.
    public T AddComponent<T>()
    {
        GenericComponent<Object> newComponent = new GenericComponent<Object>();//;(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        newComponent.component = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        componentList.Add(newComponent);
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
    //returns all components of type T
    public List<T> GetComponents<T>()
    {
        List<T> r = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < componentList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (componentList[i].component.GetType() == typeof(T))
            {
                r.Add((T)componentList[i].component);
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class GenericComponent<T> where T : new()
{
    public T component;
    public GenericComponent()
    {
        component = new T();
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class Dog
{
    public string name = "";
    public Dog() { }
    public Dog(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are confusing the concepts of `Referencing`. A list is only a way of referencing objects, its a bit like a telephone book. When you add an object to a list, all you do is put the address of the object into the list. So the object you add and the object the list refers to are one and the same.

Comment: Code in `AddComponent` does not make much sense to me as I'd expect only one object of type `T` created...

Comment: This might be of interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: One problem is that you are creating multiple instances because `Activator.CreateInstance` is called twice. The instance you return is not the one you added to the list.

Comment: @MikeCheel - it not going to help OP as "add component" actually returns completely detached copy...

Comment: I was just suggesting that he might read upon data binding. I was going off the first paragraph of his question, which made me think data binding. Reading more I guess that's not what he is interested in.

Comment: @Alexei, that's by design, trying to mimic the "AddComponent" of Unity3D. Unity 3D does not allow for serializing GameObjects so I'm having to recreate some of the methods and classes for my own functionality. A GameObject could have one component of a certain type only then you could just call "GetComponent<Type>" to get that one component you wish to modify.

My point is I'd like to keep it "attached" or whatnot so whenever a change is made to the returned object, the change is also made to that object in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AddComponent method, you are adding one component and then returning another one. Instead, return the same one you added:

```
public T AddComponent<T>()
{
    GenericComponent<Object> newComponent = new GenericComponent<Object>();
    newComponent.component = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    componentList.Add(newComponent);
    return (T)newComponent.component;
}
```

Comment: Also, if you have two dogs, PLEASE don't name them 'Fluffy' and 'Fuzzy'!!

Comment: Hahaha I'll leave those names for my grandmothers kittens.